# Always run plugin, even if page is cached via WP Rocket Cache

Tags: wordpress, caching

We develop a plugin to track page views on the server side, so it is necessary that our WordPress plugin runs each time a visitor opens a page.

This works fine via

```
$this->loader->add_action('wp', $plugin_public, 'track_page');
```

As long as WP Rocket is not installed and enabled.

With WP Rocket enabled, the hook is no longer called.

How can we make a plugin to be always executed, even the page is cached?

1. I tried a must-use plugin in `wp-content/mu-plugins/my-mu-plugin.php` and added a simple `die('this was executed')` - the line is not called when opening a cached page
2. The plugin resides normally on `wp-content/plugins`, but the entry file is also never called when serving a cached page.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of cashing **not** to load wordpress with requests?

Comment: You a right, but there still should hopefully be a way to very specifically still hook into the cached requests

Comment: You can probably even put the line `die('this was executed')` inside WordPress' `index.php` and it won't get called, so there's nothing to hook into. You can either exclude all pages from caching (with all its downsides) or exclude a specific REST route from caching and call this route via AJAX from the client for every page load (like Google Analytics does).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the comments from @volkerschulz I figured out that even `index.php` of WordPress is not hit. So there is absolutely no chance to load plugins that way.

The reason is the following rewrite rule which is inserted by WP Rocket:

```
RewriteRule .* "/wp-content/cache/wp-rocket/%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}/index%{ENV:WPR_SSL}%{ENV:WPR_WEBP}.html%{ENV:WPR_ENC}" [L]
```

This bypasses all PHP / WordPress processing and just serves the static HTML file.

That is why visitor tracking can only be done via an AJAX call or by manipulating this rewrite rule and wire-in an additional tracking script or so, which would mean a bigger change of the plugin.

The `.htaccess` code from WP Rocket can be changed in the `rocket_htaccess_marker` filter. But additionally to that rewrite rule there seems to be a cache in place which is used, if the rewrite rule fails.